# Why does a Linq query on XML file checks only the first parameter of many?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My source file is a XML file and it looks like this, but a little bit bigger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Controller Name="PLC1_0">
    <LibSolution>CMG</LibSolution>
    <LibName>1756-LxxES</LibName>       
    <LibVersion></LibVersion>
    <Parameter Name="ChassisName">Local</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="Slot">0</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="Size">4</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="SoftwareRevision">31</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="ProcessorType">1756-L83ES</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="ConfigureMotion">1</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="MotionGroupName">MotionGroup1</Parameter>
    <!--====================================================================================================================-->
    <!-- IO CONFIGURATION -->
    <!--====================================================================================================================-->
    <IOInstances>
        <Instance ModuleName="GEN1" UnitName="CAB1" SubUnitName="KF0907_2">             
            <LibSolution>CMG</LibSolution>          
            <LibName>1734-IB4/C</LibName>       
            <LibVersion></LibVersion>
            <ParentModule>CLO1_CAB1_KF0901_1</ParentModule>
            <Parameter Name="IP">80</Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="Slot">6</Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="ProgNameIO">CLX1_IO</Parameter>
        </Instance>
        
        <Instance ModuleName="GEN1" UnitName="CAB1" SubUnitName="KF0907_4">             
            <LibSolution>CMG</LibSolution>          
            <LibName>1734-IB4/C</LibName>       
            <LibVersion></LibVersion>
            <ParentModule>CLO1_CAB1_KF0901_1</ParentModule>
            <Parameter Name="IP">80</Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="Slot">7</Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="ProgNameIO">CLX1_IO</Parameter>
        </Instance>
        
        <Instance ModuleName="GEN1" UnitName="CAB1" SubUnitName="KF0907_5">             
            <LibSolution>CMG</LibSolution>          
            <LibName>1734-4IOL/A</LibName>      
            <LibVersion></LibVersion>
            <ParentModule>CLO1_CAB1_KF0901_1</ParentModule>
            <Parameter Name="Slot">8</Parameter>
        </Instance>
        
        <Instance ModuleName="GEN1" UnitName="CAB1" SubUnitName="KF0910_1">             
            <LibSolution>CMG</LibSolution>          
            <LibName>1734-OB4/C</LibName>       
            <LibVersion></LibVersion>
            <ParentModule>CLO1_CAB1_KF0901_1</ParentModule>
            <Parameter Name="IP">80</Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="Slot">9</Parameter>
            <Parameter Name="ProgNameIO">CLX1_IO</Parameter>
        </Instance>         
    </IOInstances>          
</Controller>   
</root>
```

My query targets the instances with e.g. a parameter with a special name. The problem is it looks like LinQ doesn't work like common SQL.

This query should return all instances which have a ModuleName=**GEN1** and a **Parameter** --> [Attribute] "**Name**" --> [Value] "**Slot**"

```
IEnumerable<XElement> finalObject = from node in xDocConfig.Descendants("IOInstances").Elements("Instance")
                                      where node.Attribute("ModuleName").Value.Equals("GEN1")
                                      where node.Element("Parameter").Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Slot")
                                      select node;
```

Unfortunately it returns only the second last instance of my example XML. Coincidentally, at this instance there are some parameters missing, therefore the parameter "slot" is the first one and got found by my query. If it is the second or third parameter it is not found by the query.

***I really don't know how to alter my query to get all 4 instances. I appreciate your help.***

Comment: Hmm the xml you posted gives me an error `Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: root. Line 56, position 17`

Comment: `node.Element("Parameter")` will get the first element with that name, you want to search all of them for an element with a certain attribute.

Comment: sorry, closing tag of root was there but not visible. I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Juharr, your hint guided me to a solution, it was the most helpful and very simpel.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> finalObject = from node in xDocConfig.Descendants("IOInstances").Elements("Instance") 
                                    where node.Attribute("ModuleName").Value.Equals("GEN1") 
                                    where node.Elements("Parameter").Any(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Slot")) 
                                    select node;
```

- The first line returns an enumeration.
- The second line filters this
  enumeration 'cause there is only one Attribute with that name.
- The third line has to include a "mapping", because there is more than one parameter to check. The lambda expression iterates through all parameters and .Any() returns bool values to the WHERE expression.

**Thx to all of you, I appreciate your efforts.**

Answer (score 2):

Where you have:

`where node.Element("Parameter")`

that seems to only target the first element that matches the name `"Parameter"`.

I believe there is an alternative method called `.Elements()` which you will have to use because there are multiple `Parameter` elements within the `Instance` node.

It will return an IEnumerable I believe, so you will have to change your logic to check through all the `Parameter` nodes where the attribute `Name` equals `Slot`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Elements_System_Xml_Linq_XName_

Comment: Specifically `node.Elements("Paramter").Any(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Slot"))`

Comment: Juharr, your hint guided me to a solution, please answer the question, I will mark it as most helpful.                     IEnumerable<XElement> finalObject = from node in xDocConfig.Descendants("IOInstances").Elements("Instance")
                                                        where node.Attribute("ModuleName").Value.Equals("GEN1")
                                                        where node.Elements("Parameter").Any(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Slot"))
                                                        select node;

Answer (score 2):

**Update** misunderstood the question, to return actual Instances, do this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> finalObject = xDocConfig.Descendants("IOInstances")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Instance").Where(i => i.Attribute("ModuleName").Value.Equals("GEN1")
    &&
    i.Elements("Parameter").Any(p => p.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Slot"))
    ));
```

Basically, you need to `SelectMany` to flatten the nested collections, and `Any()` to find those that contain an element inside.

Comment: This results in a collection of the Parameter elements instead of the Instance elements.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\prototype.xml";
    
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

    IEnumerable<XElement> finalObject = xdoc.Descendants("IOInstances")
        .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Instance")
            .Where(i => i.Attribute("ModuleName").Value.Equals("GEN1")
            &&
            i.Elements("Parameter").Any(p => p.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Slot"))
            )
        );

    finalObject.Dump();
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing that the OP already has and will only check against the first Paramter element in each Instance.

Comment: @juharr. You are right on target. I came with a solution that is working now. It gives many `<Instance>` elements  now.